# RadioButtonList without the Radio Button Circle?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

basically, i just want the RadioButtonList without the radio button on it, i will code the rbl so that selected items have a different background color and make it look more professional, the radio buttons themselves i want to be able to get rid of in terms of apperance... if you know of any way to do it, please do let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this helped me a lot:
>   http_://www.ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

**This link is broken**, the original owner is.. forever offline, so the content

**Perhaps** for any of you reading this, can try to set the background to none in the input in the css

```
<style>
   input {
      background:none !important;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks, this doesn't get rid of the hollow circle to the left of the radio button, however it is still a great resource and i have bookmarked it, will upvote you.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any straightforward method without mixing some tricks with javascript.

This could be something you want:
[Accessible, Custom Designed Checkbox and Radio Button Inputs Styled with CSS (and a dash of jQuery)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140403223941/http://filamentgroup.com/lab/accessible_custom_designed_checkbox_radio_button_inputs_styled_css_jquery/)

The [stand-a-lone demo here](https://www.filamentgroup.com/hey-time-traveller.html).

The image used to mimick the radio buttons: [image: Radio Button Image]
<sub>(source: [filamentgroup.com](https://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/customInput/images/radiobutton.gif))</sub>

Comment: thanks but this doesn't get rid of the hollow circle to the left of the radio button

Comment: But those are images. See my updated answer. You can create your own hollow-less circles.

Comment: i see what you're saying, thanks, will use this as a last resort, still looking for a lovely style="button: dissapear.and.dont.come.back" type css style :)

Answer (score 0):

found a plausible solution...

```
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Test - Hide radio circles from radiobuttonlist</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function hideRadioSymbol()
    {
        var rads = new Array();
        rads = document.getElementsByName('list1'); //Whatever ID u have given to ur radiolist.
        for(var i = 0; i < rads.length; i++)
            document.getElementById(rads.item(i).id).style.display = 'none'; //hide
    }
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="list1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="item1" Text="item1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="item2" Text="item2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">hideRadioSymbol()</script> //After list is completely rendered/loaded.
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

oh and btw, mvc is awesome, it's how asp.net *should* have been from the begining!!

Comment: as usual, stackoverflow just removed all of the html, not bad default logic for a code posting site!

Comment: Select the `101010` button to indent your code 4 spaces and preserve the formatting.